# Load plain/markdown text (.txt/.md) files in Middleman

Tags: ruby, markdown, middleman, static-site

Middleman automatically loads the contents of `.json` or `.yml` [data files](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/data-files/) that exist in the `/data` folder.

Is there any way to load the contents of **any** `.txt` or `.md` file inside this folder?

I found this [extension](https://github.com/stevenosloan/middleman-data_source), but I don't see how I can achieve that.

### Example

Given this structure and the following files:

```
data/
├── foo.yml
└── bar.txt
```

- `foo.yml`:

```yaml
text: "I can load this text."
```

- `bar.txt`

```
I want to load this text.
```

I can access `data.foo.text` and retrieve `I can load this text.`

I want to access `data.bar` and retrieve `I want to load this text.`

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own extension, or MonkeyPatch Middleman. Converting your text files to yaml is probably easier.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the only option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by reading the txt data (or markdown). middleman data is not intended to contain data other than array/hash form. assuming you want to load long (or formatted) text, this is better way IMO

posts.yml:

```
-
  title: First Post
  file: foo.txt
-
  title: Second Title
  file: bar.txt
```

and in your view:

```
<% data.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post[:title] %>
  <%= simple_format(File.read("data/#{post[:file]}").html_safe) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround until I figure out how to write my own extension for loading plain text files.

Having the following data file:

- **data/bar.yml**:

```yaml
---
title: bar
# Content in plain text can be placed after ---
---
## H2 test
- Hello __world__!
```

And then the content can be accessed with `data.bar.postscript`:

```
<div class="container">                 
    <h1><%= data.bar.title %></h1>
    <%= makrdown data.bar.postscript %> # In this case, I want to render it in Markdown
</div>
```

For rendering the Markdown I defined a helper function in **config.rb**:

```
helpers do 
  def markdown(text=nil)
    text ||= yield
    return Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true, tables: true).render(text)
  end
end
```